# Sum of two numbers with default maximum value that cannot be exceeded

Tags: python, sum

Suppose that I have a numeric variable which will have another value added to it, but I want to make sure that this variable never exceeds a maximum value, and upon being exceeded, will simply default to the maximum value.

For example, given a maximum value of 100, and a function which does this which is called `maxadd`:

```
input1 = 90
input2 = 8
maxadd(input1, input2, 100)
>>> 98

input1 = 95
input2 = 8
maxadd(input1, input2, 100)
>>> 100
```

I could just define it as a normal function like this:

```
def maxadd(a, b, _max):
    res = a + b
    if res > _max:
        return _max
    return res
```

But I feel like it could be done in a single line, maybe with a lambda. I can't seem to figure anything out though. Performance is also a concern so I would like the fastest solution possible, and I feel like this function may be taking unnecessary steps

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `min(a + b, max_value)`.

Answer (score 6):

Logically, you want to return either `a + b` or `_max`, whichever is smaller. So you can use the built-in function `min` for this:

```py
def maxadd(a, b, _max):
    return min(a + b, _max)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a lambda:

```
 f = lambda a, b, max_: min(a + b, max_)
```

For example:

```
f(90, 8, 100)
```

> 98

```
f(95, 8, 100)
```

> 100

Comment: How does using `lambda` (as opposed to `def f(...`) make a difference?

Comment: The difference is that using a lambda means the name `f` won't be included in the stack trace if it throws an exception (e.g. when calling `f(1, 2, None)`). That's undesirable, so generally if a function has a name then it shouldn't be a lambda.